# Language selection in TeXShop

Tags: languages, texshop

All menus in TeXShop are in German, my system language.
I want to use the program in English though, without changing my system language.
Any way to do this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Isn't there a configuration file?

Comment: Thank you. I didn't find one. I was able to 'solve' the problem, by right-clicking on TeXShop, clicking 'show content' and then deleting all language folders except for the english one in the resources folder. I'm not sure if this is the best way though.

Comment: Maybe Language Switcher (http://www.tj-hd.co.uk/en-gb/languageswitcher/) can help.